# Freemarker white space stripping

Tags: freemarker

The [Freemarker documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_whitespace.html#dgui_misc_whitespace_stripping) says:

> In practice it means that you can put empty lines between macro
>   definitions and assignments as spacing for better readability, without
>   printing needless empty lines (line breaks) to the output.

When I render the template

```
Start
<#assign var1 = "Foo"/>

<#assign var2 = "Bar"/>
End
```

the result is

```
Start
End
```

i.e. the newline between the two assignments is stripped. This is what I would expect according to the documentation. However, rendering a slightly modified template

```
Start
<#assign var1 = "Foo"/>

<#assign var2>
Bar
</#assign>
End
```

doesn't seem to remove the newline:

```
Start

End
```

Is this a bug or am I misinterpreting the documentation? I am using Freemarker 2.3.20.

Comment: Try with `<#assign var2>Bar</#assign>`.

Comment: `<#assign var2>Bar</#assign>` gives the same result (newline not removed).

Comment: Hi! did you try using <#compress></#compress> ? I was looking for the solution of another issue and I found this: http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_whitespace.html

Hope it helps you!

Comment: @adiego73: The compress directive is different as it works on the generated output, not on the template. My point was that white-space stripping doesn't seem to work with block-#assign. This was confirmed to be bug by ddekany (see below). Anyway, thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation means that you can add empty lines between these directives for better readability without adding extra line-break to the output. Also, the line-break *after* these directives is removed. In you first example, the line-break is at the end of the "Start" line.

That there's no whitespace removal between block-`#assign` and `#assign` is a bug.

Comment: So should I file a bug report?

Comment: Sure, at least it won't be forgotten.